# Doing Dexie DB refresh programmatically

Tags: dexie

My application is heavy on data and we want to save the data on UI but it would keep on changing and when it changes we want to refresh the data. How is it achievable in Dexie?

Answer (score 0):

Try the new liveQuery() that returns observable that triggers whenever change happens. See https://medium.com/dexie-js/awesome-react-integration-coming-f212c2273d05 . It's not only for react even though the blog title tasks about the react hook as well. You will need to install dexie@next for now but the release can be regarded rather stable.

Comment: I tried using this liveQuery approach am getting an erro Object(..) is not a function.
const legalEntityObservable = liveQuery (
    () => dbAdmin.table_name.bulkAdd(Object.values(getResponse('table_name'))[0])
);

Comment: Check that you're using the correct version dexie@3.1.0-alpha.6 or later. Install dexie using  npm install dexie@next.

Comment: i have "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "dexie": "^3.1.0-alpha.6",   proper version in package.json file.

Comment: Also my useLiveQuery is getting called I can check the output in my console but my liveQuery is not as I do not get any logs for

someObservable.subscribe({
  next: (result) => console.log('Got result:', result),
  error: (error) => console.error('Error',error),
});

const someObservable = liveQuery(
    () => dbAdmin.some.toArray()
);

Comment: If you have time to write a repro on https://codesandbox.io or similar, that would be great! I will look into it.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt but just an update my liveQuery did work ..

Comment: Ok, thanks! I interpret it as the issue must have been wrong version of dexie and that it was resolved by updating dexie to 3.1.0-alpha.6?

Comment: i didnt quite understand the usage of it before i was using liveQuery and useLiveQuery together :(

Comment: Hi what is the latest version now ?

Comment: You still need to npm install dexie@next (which will give you dexie@3.2.0-rc.1 - it's just about to be released as a stable soon)